# Date Mismatch Despite Date Join

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a SQL query that combines two tables based on non-unique identifiers, a date field and a string field. The problem is that my `LEFT JOIN` on both fields is delivering different results than pairing the data in a spreadsheet and it appears that part of the issue is due to joins being recognized where dates are mismatching and I'm not sure what could be causing this issue.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT *
FROM ga_page
LEFT JOIN sf_lead
    ON ga_page.date = sf_lead.lead_date::date
    AND TRIM(ga_page.page_path) = TRIM(REPLACE(sf_lead.lead_url, 'www.test.com', ''))
```

Here is `ga_page`:

```
date = 2019-06-30
page_path = /major/team
```

Here is `sf_lead`:

```
lead_date = 2019-06-30 11:25:13
lead_url = www.test.com/major/team
lead_id = 282381
```

Here is what could currently happen

```
date, lead_date, page_path, lead_url

2019-06-30, 2019-06-29, /major/team, /major/team
```

Comment: Why are you using `regexp_replace()` when `replace()` would do?

Comment: Sorry, I posted an old version. That originally had regex in it, but forgot to switch to replace. Updating the replace there

Comment: It seems that your `lead_date` field is of `TIMESTAMPTZ` type rather than `TIMESTAMP`, which is why converting it to DATE is giving a different result.

Comment: Yes, I believe the timestamp and timezone is the reason. What function would be better to use to truncate the timestamp to the just the date value without the variable of the timestamp and rounding?